# Docker on Mac M1 - Volume not able to resolve relative path

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

My directory structure is ~/db/migrations/
and I have a docker compose file . on running docker-compose up, it throws error as `error: open /db/migrations: no such file or directory` . I doubt its a bug in docker for M1. Has anyone else faced similar issue?

```
    version: '3.7'
services:
  database:
    image: postgres
    networks:
      db_network:
        aliases:
          - database_network
    env_file:
      - database.env
    volumes:
      - database-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
  migrate:
    image: migrate/migrate
    networks:
      - db_network
    volumes:
      - .:/db/migrations
    command: ["-path", "/db/migrations/", "-database",  "postgres://memories_user:memories_password@database:5432/memories_dev?sslmode=disable", "up", "3"]
    links:                                                                                                                                                                   
      - database                                                                                                                                                             
networks:                                                                                                                                                                    
  db_network:                                                                                                                                                                
volumes:                                                                                                                                                                     
  database-data: ~
```

Comment: In your volume mount, is `/db/mirations` missing a `g`?

Comment: that was a typo here. My actual file has it and its still a issue.

Answer (score 0):

A minor tweak to volumes solved it.

```
volumes:
  - ./db/migrations:/migrations
command: ["-path", "/migrations", "-database",  "postgres://memories_user:memories_password@database:5432/memories_dev?sslmode=disable", "up", "3"]
```